# No suggestions in Data Selector (Rules)

Tags: commerce, rules

following this guide to display alternative prices for certain roles: http://jamestombs.co.uk/2012-09-14/drupal-commerce-different-prices-different-customer-groups

But for some reason I don't get any suggestions or dropdown in the Data Selector field.

I've tried changing jquery versions which doesn't correct the error.

Any other ideas? I've added a detailed description of my approach below the screenshot.

It's a d7 commerce site, all modules is the latest versions

[image: screenshot]

Step by step approach to making the pricing rule

1. created 'retailer' role
2. added a new field of the type 'price' called field_ppd (ppd = price per dealer)
3. created a 'retail price' rule at admin/commerce/config/product-pricing/rules/add
4. added a 'Entity has field' condition
5. And it's in the condition config I'm stuck since the Data Selector field doesn't auto-suggest when I start typing

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please, do not restrict yourself to posting link. It will not stay valid indefinitely. Content there may change. Or maybe you misinterpreted it? So please tell us what **you** did. with **your** words. Also, please include any errors shown in JavaScript console of your browser. If your browser does not have one, use Google Chrome (built-in), Firefox (with Firebug), or, if you prefer some other brand, find out how to get it.

Comment: Thanks Sir, a link isn't possible since my site is only available locally on my own machine. The console har one error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: I meant - don't just link to a guide, tell us how you used that guide. You know, so we could tell if you made any mistake using it. Sorry for my lack of precision.

Comment: No worries, I'm grateful for your time. I've updated my initial question with my approach and a screenshot showing where I'm stuck. Do you think this is sufficient?

Comment: I hope so. Looks solid, +1 from me.

Comment: are you using the jquery update module?

Comment: yes, with google as CDN. Tried both 1.7, 1.8 & 1.9

Comment: @2pha Sorry to bug you, but do you have any ideas? also tried jQuery 1.5 & 1.6 with no luck

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug in a third-party module that was already fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in the rules module. The issue is discussed [HERE](https://www.drupal.org/node/1810656).
You can either apply the patch in the issue or use the latest dev version of the jquery update module which allows you to select the drupal default version of jquery for the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @2pha. To elaborate:

- I disabled jQuery Update, cleared the cache, checked that Rules were working (they were), reenabled jQuery Update. At this step Rules was out of order again, with 1-5 as admin and 1.8 as default. I tried changing to 1.7 as admin version, still no result. I then tried new settings in the CDN field. Having 1.7 as admin with jQuery as CDN works:)

Comment: My answer not acceptable? using the dev version of jquery update and setting the admin jquery to 'Default (provided by drupal)' will allow you to run any jquery update version and still have drupals default jquery in the backend. I recently needed this when using the bootstrap theme.

Comment: totally, sorry, marked your answer now. This is with Zen theme btw. Just marked my own elaboration as I thought this was more precise, but you should definitely get the credit for showing me in the right direction